# Equations behind mist formation around wings of fighter jet while doing acrobatic turns

Tags: aerodynamics

Can some point me around equations to study for clouds formations around fighter jets while taking turns at high speeds as witnessed in Ace Combat 7 video game.

I want to implement this phenomenon in my own open source game in unreal engine or unity3d.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can a contrail only form below -40 Degree Celsius?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380882/)

Comment: The top answer to the question I've lined includes a reference to the original paper on contrail formation. [You can download the PDF here](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0450%281995%29034%3C2400%3AAROTFO%3E2.0.CO%3B2).